# presentViewController won't work with animated:NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios6

I'm using `[self presentModalViewController:head animated:NO];` in ios 4.3 and looking for an alternative for ios 5 and up. I'd prefer using something universal for all iOS versions but `if (iOS is lower than 6)` can also be great. 
My problem is that using `[self presentViewController:head animated:YES completion:nil];` as an alternative would work **only** if `animated` is set to `YES`. Any idea why? I don't want it to animate. Is there anything else I can use if I'm **not** using `StoryBoards` ?

Comment: Can you include the code snippet to the question?

Comment: The above is the only code I'm using to move between ViewControllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the app fail at all? Have you got NSZombies enabled?

If you are doing something like this

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init]

    if (self) {
       ViewController * viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
       [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }

    return self;
}
```

This is because the view hasn't initiated yet please use one of the following methods

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];

   ViewController * viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
   [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES];

}

// OR

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   ViewController * viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
   [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES];

}
```

I understand that this might not answer your question but you did not post what initiator it is in. But this is a common error so thought I would post incase it solves your problem.

Comment: I figured it out yesterday. The code was under ViewWillAppear. Your guess was absolutely right. Thanks

Comment: excellent. i only answered that as its a common mistake glad you figured it out